# Finding the MLE of $(1-p)^3$ from a geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I found the MLE of p from this:

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3.....X_n$ be a random sample from the geometric distribution with p.d.f.
$f(x;p)=(1−p)^{x−1}p,x=1,2,3....$

The likelihood function:

$L(p)=(1−p)^{x_1−1}p(1−p)^{x_2−1}p...(1−p)^{x_n−1}p=p^n(1−p)^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i−n}$

Taking log,

$\ln L(p)=n\ln p+(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i−n)\ln(1−p)$

Differentiating and equating to zero, we get,

$\frac{d[\ln L(p)]}{dp}=\frac np−\frac{(∑^n_1x_i−n)}{(1−p)}=0$

Therefore,

$p=\frac{n}{∑^n_1x_i}$

So, the maximum likelihood estimator of P is:

$P=\frac n{∑^n_1X_i}=1/\overline X$

But I'm unsure of how to obtain the MLE of $1/p$ and $(1-p)^3$

Is it done through a similar method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should go similar way. First express $p$ through the new variable $\theta=\frac1p$ or $\theta=(1-p)^3$ and rewrite p.d.f in terms of $\theta$.

Say, for the first case $p=\frac1\theta$, 
$$
f(x;p(\theta))=\left(1−\frac1\theta\right)^{x−1}\frac1\theta,\quad x=1,2,3.\ldots.
$$

The likelihood function: 
$$
L(p(\theta))=\left(1−\frac1\theta\right)^{X_1−1}\frac1\theta \cdot \ldots \cdot \left(1−\frac1\theta\right)^{X_n−1}\frac1\theta = \dfrac{1}{\theta^n}\left(1−\frac1\theta\right)^{\sum_1^n X_i−n}
$$
It is also suitable to write $n\overline X$ instead of $\sum\limits_1^n X_i$.
$$
\ln L(p(\theta))= -n\ln \theta + (n\overline X - n)\ln\left(1−\frac1\theta\right) = -n\ln \theta + n(\overline X - 1)\bigl(\ln(\theta−1)-\ln\theta\bigr).
$$
Differentiate by $\theta$:
$$
\dfrac{dL(p(\theta))}{d\theta} = -\dfrac{n}\theta+ n(\overline X - 1)\left(\frac{1}{\theta-1}-\dfrac1\theta\right).
$$
The solution of $\dfrac{dL(p(\theta))}{d\theta}=0$ is $\hat\theta=\overline X$. We can also check that this point maximize $L(p(\theta))$. Say, the second derivative will help. It is negative at this point.

The other way is to note that $$\dfrac{dL(p(\theta))}{d\theta}=\dfrac{dL(p)}{dp}\times\dfrac{dp(\theta)}{d\theta}$$
Here $L(p(\theta))$ is your initial $L(p)$, and the first factor you have  found already. And both cases $\dfrac{dp(\theta)}{d\theta}\neq 0$ for $0<p<1$ since both functions $\theta=\frac1p$ and $\theta=(1-p)^3$  are strictly monotone.

So, the value $\hat p=\dfrac{1}{\overline X}$ which causes $\dfrac{dL(p)}{dp}$ equal to zero, does the same with $\dfrac{dL(p(\theta))}{d\theta}$.
And you need only to solve 
$$
\hat p=\dfrac{1}{\overline X} = \frac{1}{\hat\theta}, \quad \hat\theta = \overline X.
$$

Edit: Note that you can use the [invariance property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance) and write out both estimates immediately, instead of finding them by definition.

Comment: Couldn't we simply invoke the invariance property (e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/77573) of MLE's?

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Of course, we can simply use the invariance property, provided that it is known to the OP. I'm afraid that in this case, the exercise assumes finding MLE directly, without such properties. Otherwise, it seems to me that the question would hardly have arisen.

Comment: Fair enough. The question and the OP's visits have been more than a year old, but it was bumped to the homepage. Re-reading the OP's question carefully, I don't see anything specifically that insists finding the MLE directly. So if the OP is simply not seeing that the invariance property can be used, I figured it is worth bringing that up (for the OP or for others who may come across this question). Perhaps you may consider adding a one line note to your answer because the comments could possibly disappear.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Thank you, I will do it. Although frankly, both the question and the answer hardly deserve to be kept here forever.